# getElementsByTagName está retornando valores errados

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou tentando fazer uma tabela do HTML selecionável, quando tento pegar as linhas da tabela pelo `getElementsByTagName()`, está retornando valores distintos quando recarrego a página.

Minhas Tabela:

[image: Minhas Tabela:]

JavaScript:

```
var tabela = document.getElementById("listSensors");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");
console.log(linhas);
console.log(linhas.length);
```

Retornos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me parece que é algo relacionado a tempo de execução, alguma sugestão para resolver?

Comment: Sobre o HTML, evite postar imagem do código. Prefira postar o código na pergunta. Neste [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485) você vai entender o porquê :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque o seu código javascript antes do fechamento da tag `</body>` para assegurar que todo conteúdo HTML foi carregado. Além disso, utilize o evento `onload` para garantir que o javascript será executado após o carregamento.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tabela = document.getElementById("listSensors");
    var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    console.log(linhas);
    console.log(linhas.length);
};
```